# Pass regex replace match to a function

Tags: javascript

I want to add a span tag with a class to style with css around content in a string that matches a regex, and is in a set of accepted values.

For instance with a regex `/fo./` I'd want to turn `barfoobarfoafoc` into

```
bar<span class = "stylename">foo</span>bar<span class = "stylename">foa</span>foc
```

if both foo and foa are in the set of accepted strings, but foc is not.

I've played around with String.replace(), but I can't find the way to get the matched content into a verification function So I tried:

```
output = output.replace(/fo./g,isAcceptedValue("$&"));
```

but the parameter passed to replace is just "$&" rather than the matched string.  Which probably shouldn't have been surprising.  Is there a way to do this using the replace function?  Or am I going to have to manually get each regex return and replace the substring from the start of the match and all of that?  I was hoping there was a way to do this during replace so the code is clear about what its doing and I don't have to deal with calculating the substrings.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the last example.

Comment: That looks promising thanks!

Comment: @FelixKling yep that works.  just had to remove 6 characters, the `("$&")` and it worked as desired.  Thanks.  Feel free to put it as an answer if you like and I'll accept.